# Little o-notation, convergence and random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation

If $x_n$ is a deterministic sequence and $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, we can write $x_n = x+o(1)$, right? Can one do the same for random variables? Namely, if $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables and $X_n \to X_\infty$ a.s. as $n \to \infty$, can we write $X_n = X_\infty + o(1)?$ My intuition says no, but why exactly not? I suppose the difference $o(1)$ must be random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  nothing wrong in saying ht $X_n=X+o(1)$ almost surely but it should be remembered there is no uniformity w.r.t. $\omega$: $\sup_{\omega} |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|$ need not tend to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then, couldn't I always write: $EX_n = E(X + o(1)) = EX + Eo(1)$ and thus as $n \to \infty$ that $\lim_n  EX_n = EX$ which is not true in general?

Comment: @BenC. You cannot say anything about $Eo(1)$. $o(1)$ is not sequnce of numbers tending to $0$. It is a sequence of random variables.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. But the sequence of random variables is still converging to $0$ a.s., right?